# How to find the derivative of one matrix with respect to another?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, implicit

I have an expression from a continuum model,which looks somewhat like this excluding a few constants.
[image]

Here epsilon is the 3x3 strain tensor and sigma is 3x3 stress tensor. I wish to compute the derivative of sigma with respect to epsilon. As you may see, it is an implicit relation and it is posing some challenges which I am unable to work around.

I have tried using the `ImplicitD` function, which works well for computing the derivative of implicit scalar functions. For instance, if y = sin(y)+x , then the derivative of y with respect to x is 1/(1-cos(y)). This is correctly computed by the `ImplicitD` function in Mathematica.

```
ImplicitD[y, Sin[y] + x - y == 0, y, x]
```

returns

```
1/(1 - Cos[y])
```

as expected.
However, when I tried using `ImplicitD` for the same for the matrix expression mentioned above,

```
ImplicitD[sig, -1/(1 - Tr[eps])*Tr[sig]*IdentityMatrix[3] + 1/(1 - Tr[eps])*sig - eps == 0, eps]
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Please help. I am new to this forum, and please pardon the difficulties caused earlier.

Comment: You have probably posted this question on the wrong site. This site is about _Wolfram Mathematica Software_, while your question is about mathematics, and should be posted on [Mathematic**s** StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, I know to compute the derivative by hand. I want to know how to do the same operation, specifically in Mathematica.

Comment: Then please include all relevant information: (1) how to compute the derivative by hand, and (2) Mathematica code for your tensors or whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html),not images. 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: If you are unable to do all the things that @rhermans thoroughly explained, at least give a **PROPER** mathematical description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what the derivative relative to a matrix means. I assume that you mean the derivative relative to each matrix element. This can be done with "D".

For simplicity to get you started, here is a 2D example: To get the derivative of matrix ms relative to matrix me, we must write the matrix elements of ms as functions of the elements of me:

```
n = 2;
me = Array[e, {n, n}];
vars = Flatten[me]
ms = Array[(StringJoin["s", ToString[#1], ToString[#2]] @@ 
     vars) &, {n, n}]
```

[image]

Now, for your problem, we first solve the implicit equation for the elements of matrix sigma, then we replace the elements of sigma by the solutions and do the derivative:

```
sig = Array[
  Symbol@StringJoin["s", ToString[#1], ToString[#2]] &, {n, n}]
sol = Solve[-1/(1 - Tr[eps])*Tr[sig]*IdentityMatrix[2] + 
    1/(1 - Tr[eps])*sig - eps == 0, Flatten[sig]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
sig1 = sig /. sol[[1]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
D[sig1, {{Flatten[eps]}}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer sir! This is exactly what I was looking for.